# Custom error message based on an id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm displaying records from a table in an html table using a for loop. In each row, the `Amount` value will differ in format--some will have 4 decimal places, some 3 decimal places, and some will be currency. If you look at the textboxfor portion you'll also see I'm using a `Format` method to format the data based on `CategoryId`.

Furthermore, some of the `Amount`s are percentages and need to be validated to see if they are less then one. The problem is they all use the same `Amount` property so simply decorating with a Validation attribute is tricky.

I had no problem using the `[Required]` attribute (see below). However, I'm not sure how to validate the percentages. Is there a way I could use the `CategoryId` to generate a custom error message that will be seen in the `ValidationMessageFor`?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllGradesParamList.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model.CategoryList.Where(x => x.Id == Model.AllGradesParamList[i].CategoryId).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault()
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.AllGradesParamList[i].CategoryId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.AllGradesParamList[i].Amount, new { @Value = Model.Format(Model.AllGradesParamList[i].Amount, Model.AllGradesParamList[i].CategoryId) })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.AllGradesParamList[i].Amount)
        </td>
    </tr>
 }
```

Partial class (the rest of the class is auto generated, including the CategoryId):

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CS_Parameter_Statewide_AllGrades_ScenarioMetaData))]
public partial class CS_Parameter_Statewide_AllGrades_Scenario
{   
    public int Category { get; set; }

    public class CS_Parameter_Statewide_AllGrades_ScenarioMetaData
    {
        [Required]
        [ValidAmountAttribute("CategoryId")]
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Edit: I also started creating this custom attribute, but it's not working the way I want. Unlike the `[Required]` attribute the invalid values are sent to post. How can I prevent the values from going to post and display the errors in the `ValidationMessageFor`?

***Edit: My attempt implementing `IClientValidatable` does not seem to be working. On the server side I am calling `ModelState.IsValid` and that is working but it shouldn't even make it that far. Do I have to write additional Javascript to get it working? Maybe some how use `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add()`?

```
public class ValidAmountAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable // IClientValidatable for client side Validation
{
    private readonly string _categoryId;
    public ValidAmountAttribute(string categoryId)
    {
        _categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var catId = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_categoryId).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        var amountProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("Amount");

        double amountValue = (double)amountProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if ((catId == 212 || catId == 213) && amountValue > 1)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Amount is not valid");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { new ModelClientValidationRule { ValidationType = "textbox", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } };
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note: You should be using the overload of `TextBoxFor()` that accepts a format string, not trying to set the `value` attribute

Comment: Looks like you really should be using a view model that has the properties you want to display/edit and validate

Comment: `Amount` is the property I want to display. It just has different ways it needs to be formatted and validated. Unfortunately, this is dictated by the db table. `Amount` is a column in the table

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to have an `Amount` property for each category ID.

Comment: I understand that, but setting the `value` attribute as you have has consequences particularly for validation (your overriding the `ModelState` value if you return the view). I would consider a view model that contains the properties plus another property, say `string FormatString` that you can use in `@Html.TextBoxFor()`. In the controller, your set the `FormatString` to `"{0:0.000}"` or whatever based on some other condition.

Comment: As you mentioned, I can use the overload for `TextBoxFor()` to format the display. My real issue is the validation part. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66086/discussion-between-navig8tr-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

You can build Custom Validation Attribute of your own.

```
public class ValidAmount : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string[] memberNames = { "Amount" };
        var amountProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("Amount");

        double amountValue = (double)amountProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        // at this stage you have "amount value"
        // here you are verifying whether amount is less than 1
        if (amountValue<1)
        {
            // here you return your custom error message
            return new ValidationResult("Amount is not valid",memberNames);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Apply your custom validation attribute into model/viewmodel's property. Like this-

```
    [ValidAmount]
    public double Amount { get; set; }
```

You can also validate two properties in single validation attribute class. Follow this link for this- [How to create a custom validation attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959431/how-to-create-a-custom-validation-attribute)

Comment: Will this display the error message in the `ValidationMessageFor`?

Comment: Yes this will display ValidationMessageFor as other built in Validation Attribute

Comment: Let me know if you need to use CategoryId into that Validation logic of ValidAmount and you can not do this

Comment: In my last edit I started using category id. I might be ale to figure it out.

Comment: I tried what you said but invalid values are being sent to post. The '[Required]` attribute prevents the values from going to post. How can I get this custom attribute to work on the client side? I edited the original post to show my changes.

Comment: Can you tell me why do you need categoryId there? you have initialized catId but not used.

Comment: I only want to verify that those values, with those category ids, are less than one. Other values with other category ids will be validated differently, but I haven't written the logic for that.

Comment: Btw, the category id part works fine. You may be seeing an earlier edit.

Comment: @navig8tr, If you want client side validation, then you need to implement `IClientValidatable` and add methods for use by jquery-validate and jquery-validate-unobtrusive

Comment: Oh okay. But that doesn't have to be used when using the `[Required]` attribute?