# How to validate uploaded file in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and I'm using model binding for uploading file.

This is my **UserViewModel**

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a file.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}
```

This is **MyView**

```
@model UserViewModel

<form method="post"
      asp-action="UploadPhoto"
      asp-controller="TestFileUpload"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <input asp-for="Photo" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Photo" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

And finally this is **MyController**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPhoto(UserViewModel userViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var formFile = userViewModel.Photo;
        if (formFile == null || formFile.Length == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Uploaded file is empty or null.");
            return View(viewName: "Index");
        }

        var uploadsRootFolder = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        if (!Directory.Exists(uploadsRootFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadsRootFolder);
        }

        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsRootFolder, formFile.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(viewName: "Index");
}
```

How can I limit uploaded files to lower than 5MB with specific extensions like .jpeg and .png ? I think  both of these validations are done in the ViewModel. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2? Are you running on IIS?

Comment: @mjwills yes I'm running on IIS. I've read Microsoft docs but I didn't find anything useful for this situation

Comment: What did that page say about `maxAllowedContentLength`?

Comment: @mjwills it limits **all** upload requests heavier than 50 MB. I just want to limit upload files lower than 5MB in a specific page. And in another page for example 20 MB and in  another page 30MB did u got it ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=maxallowedcontentlength+for+specific+page

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You could custom validation attribute `MaxFileSizeAttribute` like below

**MaxFileSizeAttribute**

```
public class MaxFileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _maxFileSize;
    public MaxFileSizeAttribute(int maxFileSize)
    {
        _maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
    object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as IFormFile;
        if (file != null)
        {
           if (file.Length > _maxFileSize)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"Maximum allowed file size is { _maxFileSize} bytes.";
    }
}
```

**AllowedExtensionsAttribute**

```
public class AllowedExtensionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _extensions;
    public AllowedExtensionsAttribute(string[] extensions)
    {
        _extensions = extensions;
    }
    
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
    object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as IFormFile;
        if (file != null)
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (!_extensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
            }
        }
        
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"This photo extension is not allowed!";
    }
}
```

Add `MaxFileSize` attribute and `AllowedExtensions` attribute to `Photo` property

```
public class UserViewModel
{
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a file.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [MaxFileSize(5* 1024 * 1024)]
        [AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpg", ".png" })]
        public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Good solution! But could you Edit ur answer and make two separate validation  Attributes. One for **MaxFileSize** and another for **AllowedExtensions**. Cause based on **SOLID** principles every attribute should have a single responsiblity.

Comment: @ArianShahalami , Check the updated in my reply . If you find my workaround works, could you mark my reply as the answer ?

Comment: Really cool answer, had no idea you could make custom validation attributes!

Comment: This is extension-base. What about spoofing? I take `exe`, change extension to `txt` . .

Comment: How do I get this to interrupt my controller and display an error on the UI? I'm hitting the GetErrorMessage() method but my controller just keeps running.

Comment: @XueliChen I need to validated mp4 video for max size how can I validate it, in need to send video max length 100-MB and extension only mp4. And I need to send custom message for different model, how can I send it.

Comment: Validating file by its extension (name) is not secure. See [File signature validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#validation) section in official MS docs. You should be comparing _signature_ of the file with a pre-defined list.

Comment: @FFFffff edit this answer and include your signature validation, which would make this the ideal answer please :)

Comment: Note that this is server-side validation only. If you want client-side validation, you need to implement your own. Follow this to implement client-side validation for cutom attributes:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mvpawardprogram/asp-net-core-mvc

Comment: Not sure why my MaxFileSizeAttribute never gets called even though it exists and MaxFileSize is already applied. Breakpoint doesn't get caught. I haven't tried the extension one. Any clue?

Answer (score 15):

Above solutions are validating file by its extension (which is just the filename really). That's not secure, as it allows loading executables (pretending to be image or so).

You should be comparing *signature* of the file with a pre-defined list of allowed signatures. See the [File signature validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#validation) section in MS docs.

I then call the `IsFileValid()` method from controllers.

```
public static bool IsFileValid(IFormFile file)
{
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        var signatures = _fileSignatures.Values.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();  // flatten all signatures to single list
        var headerBytes = reader.ReadBytes(_fileSignatures.Max(m => m.Value.Max(n => n.Length)));
        bool result = signatures.Any(signature => headerBytes.Take(signature.Length).SequenceEqual(signature));
        return result;
    }
}

private static readonly Dictionary<string, List<byte[]>> _fileSignatures = new()
{
    { ".gif", new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38 } } },
    { ".png", new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A } } },
    { ".jpeg", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0 },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE2 },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE3 },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xEE },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xDB },
        }
    },
    { ".jpeg2000", new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x6A, 0x50, 0x20, 0x20, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x87, 0x0A } } },
    
    { ".jpg", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0 },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE1 },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE8 },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xEE },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xDB },
        }
    },
    { ".zip", new List<byte[]> //also docx, xlsx, pptx, ...
        {
            new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x03, 0x04 },
            new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x49, 0x54, 0x45 },
            new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x53, 0x70, 0x58 },
            new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x05, 0x06 },
            new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x07, 0x08 },
            new byte[] { 0x57, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0x69, 0x70 },
        }
    },

    { ".pdf", new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46 } } },
    { ".z", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0x1F, 0x9D },
            new byte[] { 0x1F, 0xA0 }
        }
    },
    { ".tar", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0x75, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x72, 0x00, 0x30 , 0x30 },
            new byte[] { 0x75, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x72, 0x20, 0x20 , 0x00 },
        }
    },
    { ".tar.z", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0x1F, 0x9D },
            new byte[] { 0x1F, 0xA0 }
        }
    },
    { ".tif", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00 },
            new byte[] { 0x4D, 0x4D, 0x00, 0x2A }
        }
    },
    { ".tiff", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00 },
            new byte[] { 0x4D, 0x4D, 0x00, 0x2A }
        }
    },
    { ".rar", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0x52, 0x61, 0x72, 0x21, 0x1A, 0x07 , 0x00 },
            new byte[] { 0x52, 0x61, 0x72, 0x21, 0x1A, 0x07 , 0x01, 0x00 },
        }
    },
    { ".7z", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0x37, 0x7A, 0xBC, 0xAF, 0x27 , 0x1C },
        }
    },
    { ".txt", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB , 0xBF },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFE},
            new byte[] { 0xFE, 0xFF },
            new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0xFE, 0xFF },
        }
    },
    { ".mp3", new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFB },
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xF3},
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xF2},
            new byte[] { 0x49, 0x44, 0x43},
        }
    },
};
```

More signatures can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

Answer (score 7):

This is how I use the custom validation attributes, almost the same as @xueli-chen 's answer but production-ready.

`FileExtensionsAttribute`

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

using NewsPassWebApi.Properties;

namespace NewsPassWebApi.Models.DataAnnotaions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Validation attribute to assert an <see cref="IFormFile">IFormFile</see> property, field or parameter has a specific extension.
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class FileExtensionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private string _extensions;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the acceptable extensions of the file.
        /// </summary>
        public string Extensions
        {
            get
            {
                // Default file extensions match those from jquery validate.
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_extensions) ? "png,jpg,jpeg,gif" : _extensions;
            }
            set
            {
                _extensions = value;
            }
        }

        private string ExtensionsNormalized
        {
            get
            {
                return Extensions.Replace(" ", "", StringComparison.Ordinal).ToUpperInvariant();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parameterless constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public FileExtensionsAttribute() : base(() => Resources.FileExtensionsAttribute_ValidationError)
        { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Override of <see cref="ValidationAttribute.IsValid(object)"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method returns <c>true</c> if the <paramref name="value"/> is null.  
        /// It is assumed the <see cref="RequiredAttribute"/> is used if the value may not be null.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="value">The value to test.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the value is null or its extension is included in the set extensions</returns>
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            // Automatically pass if value is null. RequiredAttribute should be used to assert a value is not null.
            if (value == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // We expect a cast exception if the passed value was not an IFormFile.
            return ExtensionsNormalized.Split(",").Contains(Path.GetExtension(((IFormFile)value).FileName).ToUpperInvariant());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Override of <see cref="ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name to include in the formatted string</param>
        /// <returns>A localized string to describe the acceptable extensions</returns>
        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, Extensions);
        }
    }
}
```

`FileSizeAttribute`

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

using NewsPassWebApi.Properties;

namespace NewsPassWebApi.Models.DataAnnotaions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Validation attribute to assert an <see cref="IFormFile">IFormFile</see> property, field or parameter does not exceed a maximum size.
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class FileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the maximum acceptable size of the file.
        /// </summary>
        public long MaximumSize { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the minimum acceptable size of the file.
        /// </summary>
        public int MinimumSize { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor that accepts the maximum size of the file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="maximumSize">The maximum size, inclusive.  It may not be negative.</param>
        public FileSizeAttribute(int maximumSize) : base(() => Resources.FileSizeAttribute_ValidationError)
        {
            MaximumSize = maximumSize;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Override of <see cref="ValidationAttribute.IsValid(object)"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method returns <c>true</c> if the <paramref name="value"/> is null.  
        /// It is assumed the <see cref="RequiredAttribute"/> is used if the value may not be null.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="value">The value to test.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the value is null or it's size is less than or equal to the set maximum size</returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> is thrown if the current attribute is ill-formed.</exception>
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            // Check the lengths for legality
            EnsureLegalSizes();

            // Automatically pass if value is null. RequiredAttribute should be used to assert a value is not null.
            // We expect a cast exception if the passed value was not an IFormFile.
            var length = value == null ? 0 : ((IFormFile)value).Length;

            return value == null || (length >= MinimumSize && length <= MaximumSize);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Override of <see cref="ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name to include in the formatted string</param>
        /// <returns>A localized string to describe the maximum acceptable size</returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> is thrown if the current attribute is ill-formed.</exception>
        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            EnsureLegalSizes();

            string errorMessage = MinimumSize != 0 ? Resources.FileSizeAttribute_ValidationErrorIncludingMinimum : ErrorMessageString;

            // it's ok to pass in the minLength even for the error message without a {2} param since String.Format will just ignore extra arguments
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, errorMessage, name, MaximumSize, MinimumSize);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks that MinimumSize and MaximumSize have legal values.  Throws InvalidOperationException if not.
        /// </summary>
        private void EnsureLegalSizes()
        {
            if (MaximumSize < 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.FileSizeAttribute_InvalidMaxSize);
            }

            if (MaximumSize < MinimumSize)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.RangeAttribute_MinGreaterThanMax, MaximumSize, MinimumSize));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now you can use those like any built-in validation attribute including custom/localized error messages, max-min file sizes, and file extensions.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement `IValidatableObject` to validate your model.

```
public class UserViewModel : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a file.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var photo = ((UserViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance).Photo;
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(photo.FileName);
            var size = photo.Length;

            if (!extension.ToLower().Equals(".jpg"))
                yield return new ValidationResult("File extension is not valid.");

           if(size > (5 * 1024 * 1024))
                yield return new ValidationResult("File size is bigger than 5MB.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested on .Net 5. How about more elastic attribute with custom `object` (you can use own ActionResult class)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MaxFileSizeAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public MaxFileSizeAttribute(int sizeInByte) { this._maxFileSize = sizeInByte; }
    private int _maxFileSize;
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (
            context
            .HttpContext
            .Request
            .Form != null
            && context.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Count > 0
            )
        {

            if (
                context
                .HttpContext
                .Request
                .Form
                .Files
                .Any(x => x.Length >= _maxFileSize)
                )
            {
                context
                    .Result = new ObjectResult($"Max file size is {_maxFileSize} bytes"
                    /*put here whatever object you want*/)
                    {
                        StatusCode = 413 //Payload Too Large
                    };
            } else { await next(); }
        } else { await next(); }

    }
}
```

And use it in controller:

```
[MaxFileSize(1024)]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendImages([FromForm] SendAttachment request)
{
 return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56600245/3262211), you can add this class:

```
public class ValidateModelStateFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        var validationErrors = context.ModelState
            .Keys
            .SelectMany(k => context.ModelState[k].Errors)
            .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
            .ToArray();

        var json = new JsonErrorResponse
        {
            Messages = validationErrors
        };

        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(json);
    }
}
```

Finally, add the filter to the controllers in Startup class:

```
 services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelStateFilter));
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Secure Extension Validation**

With the help of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59094019/3944285) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73068336/3944285) I could come up with a combined solution which works as a **DataAnnotation** also prevents files like **exe** from being injected maliciously. As explained well by [FFFffff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11035142/fffffff), checking extensions strings only

> allows loading executables (pretending to be image or so)

So Here it is:

```
public class AllowedFileExtensions : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as IFormFile;
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (!IsFileValid(file))
            {
                // get the allowed extensions to show in ValidationResult
                string? keys = null;
                foreach (var key in _fileSignatures.Keys)
                {
                    keys += key + ", ";
                }

                return new ValidationResult($"File type is not allowed. These extensions are allowed only: {keys}");
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }


    public static bool IsFileValid(IFormFile file)
    {
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            var signatures = _fileSignatures.Values.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();  // flatten all signatures to single list
            var headerBytes = reader.ReadBytes(_fileSignatures.Max(m => m.Value.Max(n => n.Length)));
            bool result = signatures.Any(signature => headerBytes.Take(signature.Length).SequenceEqual(signature));
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, List<byte[]>> _fileSignatures = new()
    {
        { ".jpeg", new List<byte[]>
            {
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0 },
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE2 },
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE3 },
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xEE },
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xDB },
            }
        },
        { ".jpg", new List<byte[]>
            {
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0 },
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE1 },
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE8 },
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xEE },
                new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xDB },
            }
        },
        { ".jpeg2000", new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x6A, 0x50, 0x20, 0x20, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x87, 0x0A } } },
        { ".png", new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A } } },
        // { ".gif", new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38 } } },
        // { ".zip", new List<byte[]> //also docx, xlsx, pptx, ...
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x03, 0x04 },
        //         new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x49, 0x54, 0x45 },
        //         new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x53, 0x70, 0x58 },
        //         new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x05, 0x06 },
        //         new byte[] { 0x50, 0x4B, 0x07, 0x08 },
        //         new byte[] { 0x57, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0x69, 0x70 },
        //     }
        // },

        // { ".pdf", new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46 } } },
        // { ".z", new List<byte[]>
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0x1F, 0x9D },
        //         new byte[] { 0x1F, 0xA0 }
        //     }
        // },
        // { ".tar", new List<byte[]>
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0x75, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x72, 0x00, 0x30 , 0x30 },
        //         new byte[] { 0x75, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x72, 0x20, 0x20 , 0x00 },
        //     }
        // },
        // { ".tar.z", new List<byte[]>
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0x1F, 0x9D },
        //         new byte[] { 0x1F, 0xA0 }
        //     }
        // },
        // { ".tif", new List<byte[]>
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00 },
        //         new byte[] { 0x4D, 0x4D, 0x00, 0x2A }
        //     }
        // },
        // { ".tiff", new List<byte[]>
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00 },
        //         new byte[] { 0x4D, 0x4D, 0x00, 0x2A }
        //     }
        // },
        // { ".rar", new List<byte[]>
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0x52, 0x61, 0x72, 0x21, 0x1A, 0x07 , 0x00 },
        //         new byte[] { 0x52, 0x61, 0x72, 0x21, 0x1A, 0x07 , 0x01, 0x00 },
        //     }
        // },
        // { ".7z", new List<byte[]>
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0x37, 0x7A, 0xBC, 0xAF, 0x27 , 0x1C },
        //     }
        // },
        // { ".txt", new List<byte[]>
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB , 0xBF },
        //         new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFE},
        //         new byte[] { 0xFE, 0xFF },
        //         new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0xFE, 0xFF },
        //     }
        // },
        // { ".mp3", new List<byte[]>
        //     {
        //         new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFB },
        //         new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xF3},
        //         new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xF2},
        //         new byte[] { 0x49, 0x44, 0x43},
        //     }
        // },
    };
}
```

I purposely commented some extensions from the **_fileSignatures** Dictionary to block them.

Now just add **[AllowedFileExtensions]** to your Controller's method signature directly or Model:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPhoto([AllowedFileExtensions] IFormFile file) { }
```

Here is the output if a non-allowed file is selected:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-94aa03b188cdf7c402ff22d809ad1bd4-4c1a49080c27213d-00",
    "errors": {
        "files": [
            "File type is not allowed. These extensions are allowed only: .jpeg, .jpg, .jpeg2000, .png, "
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick one if anyone is looking for a PDF file validator:

```
 { ".pdf", new List<byte[]> { new byte[] { 0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46 } } },
```

See the brilliant site:

https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html