# Is it possible to have a conditional Required DataAnnotation for validation using Blazor/EditForm?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Right now I have something like this in my model class:

```
        [Required]
        public bool IsNullable { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Default value is too long.")]
        public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
```

I would like to have it so that DefaultValue is only required if isNullable is false. Is there a way to do this? I have been trying to find a solution but still have not found anything useful. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This question has been answered before.  Please see the link below:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642328/how-to-put-conditional-required-attribute-into-class-property-to-work-with-web-a

Comment: You can write your own validation attribute, Auguste has commented or use IValidatableObject for validation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588900/how-to-validate-uploaded-file-in-asp-net-core/56600245#56600245)

Comment: https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations did the job.Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!