# How to handle form error of Form value length limit exceeded in asp.net core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core

In my case, I am working on ASP.NET Core 5 project and I need to limit the maximum size for the entire form content to 2MB.

I have added the following attribute to my controller

```
[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 2)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
  ...
}
```

but the problem is that anytime a user tries to upload an image or any other form item that makes the entire content of the form to be more than 2MB, the application returns a 404 error.

I am looking for a way to rather display an error message when the entire content of the form exceeds 2MB.

I will appreciate any guide to handle this error gracefully instead of the 404 error it currently displays to users

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client side you can do something similar to this to check for file size:

```
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function () {
    if (this.files[0].size > 2000000000) {
        alert("Please upload a file less than 2GB.");
        $(this).val('');
    }
   }
```

On the server side you can have a property IFormFile and check the size.
`file.FormFile.Length > 5 * 1024 * 1024;`

Or you can create a custom Validation Attribute which I prefer. This should help you get started.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592790/9936356

Comment: This is a great answer. It is very enlightening. Please, is there a way to make the custom validation or client side validation for the entire form, instead of for just a file field in the form? I need to control the max size of the entire form.

Comment: take a look at this for Model validation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0. and take a look at this for file uploading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: None of those links talks about or solves my problem